# webapi with basic authorize

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services

I've created a WebApi with .NET.
I want to secure some methods.
I would like only the users in aspnetuser table can execute this methods

I've created as

```html
public class BasicAuthHttpModule : IHttpModule
```

and in the web.config I configured this as

```html
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <add name="BasicAuthHttpModule" type="WebHostBasicAuth.Modules.BasicAuthHttpModule"/>
    </modules>    
</system.webServer>
```

And my BasicAuthHttpModule.cs:
I check the email and password with the aspnetusers tabla

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;

using Microsoft.Owin;
using ServicioProx360.Models;
using ServicioProx360;


namespace WebHostBasicAuth.Modules
 {
 public class BasicAuthHttpModule: IHttpModule
  {
  private const string Realm = "WebAPI Authentication";

  public void Init(HttpApplication context)
   {
   // Se registran los manejadores de los eventos
   context.AuthenticateRequest += OnApplicationAuthenticateRequest;
   context.EndRequest += OnApplicationEndRequest;
   }

  private static void SetPrincipal(IPrincipal principal)
   {
   Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
   if (HttpContext.Current != null)
    {
    HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
    }
   }

  private static bool AuthenticateUser(string credentials)
   {
   var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
   credentials = encoding.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(credentials));

   var credentialsArray = credentials.Split(':');
   var username = credentialsArray[0];
   var password = credentialsArray[1];

   var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));

   ApplicationUser usuario = manager.Find(username, password);
   /* Aquí se validan las credenciales o el token enviado en el encabezado de la solicitud */
//   if (!(username == "test" && password == "test"))
   if (usuario==null)
    {
    return false;
    }
   
   var identity = new GenericIdentity(usuario.UserName);
   
   SetPrincipal(new GenericPrincipal(identity, new string[] { "CIUDADADNO" }));

   return true;
   }

  private static void OnApplicationAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
   var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
   var authHeader = request.Headers["Authorization"];
   if (authHeader != null)
    {
    var authHeaderVal = AuthenticationHeaderValue.Parse(authHeader);

    // Se valida si el esquema de autenticación es básico (Basic Authentication)
    if (authHeaderVal.Scheme.Equals("basic", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && authHeaderVal.Parameter != null)
     {
     AuthenticateUser(authHeaderVal.Parameter);
     }
    }
   }

  // Si la solicitud no fue aprobada, se agrega el encabezado WWW-Authenticate a la respuesta

  private static void OnApplicationEndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
   var response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
   if (response.StatusCode == 401)
    {
    response.Headers.Add("WWW-Authenticate", string.Format("Basic realm=\"{0}\"", Realm));
    }
   }
  public void Dispose()
   {
   }
  }
 }
```

but it doen't work fine. if method is [authorize], it ask me for the email and password,I put correct data, but it ask again, again,again.

Can you help me?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this tutorial, it explains pretty well.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/basic-authentication

Comment: I look the page, and I discover: if when I create a new webservices, I choose witout authentication, it Works fine. but if I choose individual acount user, doen't work. why?